# Help with configuring the @webroot alias

Tags: config, configuration, alias

I have a hosting account running Craft 4.4.17 with a structure like this:

```
home/
    accname/
        craft's usual files and folder arrangement
        domainname.tld <-- web root
            index.php
```

I'm struggling to define the path for the `@webroot` alias in `config/general.php` so that it evaluates to `/home/accname/domainname.tld`. That's what supposed to happen right?

Is there an invariant way to express the path that should work for this structure or is it subject to hosting variables I don't have sight of?

Doesn't `dirname(__DIR__)` in this context evaluate to `home/accname` ? – and therefore the following *should* work:

```
'@webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/domainname.tld',
```

For some reason that doesn't work but I don't know why. Perhaps I have fundamentally misunderstood something.

Why I say it doesn't work is because when I set a Filesystem's `Base path` *explicitly* with something like:

```
/home/accname/domainname.tld/assets/general
```

…file uploads, previews, and transforms work.

But when I use the above `dirname` strategy and apply:

```
@webroot/assets/general
```

…things break.

Answer (score 1):

We put all of Craft's codebase into a craft folder where I work, so its along the same type of edit as what you're experiencing. Here's where you need to edit:

1. general.php config file `'@webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/domainname.tld',` you already did this, great!
2. bootstrap.php file
3. Craft executable file

Try that out!